# circular dependency between lsb-release and python3 (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python3, lsb-release

I've managed to get into a situation where I have a circular dependency between lsb-release and python3.  When I try to `sudo apt install python3 --reinstall` I get the following (just pasting the key lines)

```
(Reading database ... 470097 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.6.7-1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

[~] lsb_release
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fa905a81740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Clearly my lsb_release is broken. But if I run `sudo apt-get install lsb-release` I get

```
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-release:
 lsb-release depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
```

So I can't fix my python3 installation without fixing lsb-release, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your Python installation without fixing `lsb_release`. Your Python installation needs other Python packages to be reinstalled; at least

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libpython3.6-minimal
```

and perhaps more. To reinstall all the packages, run

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libpython3.6{,-minimal,-stdlib} python3.6{,-minimal}
```

You should then find that `lsb_release` works fine.